# ExpressJS appears to be a String Type despite being an Object Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The data type requested by the client is an object.

```
[
   {"test": "test", "test2": "test2"},
   {...},
   ...
]
```

However, ExpressJS's request appears as a String type.

```
console.log(req.body.data); // [{...},{...}]
console.log(typeof req.body.data); // String
```

MIME: `application/json`

How can I use this as an object?

I've tried converting like this but it's still a string type.

```
const test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(req.body.data));
console.log(typeof test); // String
```

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: If I don't use stringify I get an error saying that the token '' ' "doesn't exist.

The reason is that the type is a string, but the data itself doesn't have quotes.

Comment: Are you using ```app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());```? If not try adding them and also require bodyParser when you add them

Comment: @Mohammed Amir Ansrari
I am using Express 4.16.3 so no bodyParser is needed.

And I tried extended: true but the same thing happens.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your array in an object?

Eg. instead of [{ ...}, ...] do { items: [{ ...}, ...]}.It seems like express has trouble with JSON responses that are technically arrays, not objects.